# Nodejs setInterval - call a function that returns a promise and execute x times with delay

Tags: node.js, setinterval

I cannot figure this out..

I want to execute a function multiple times with a delay after each call. This is easily achieved by using setInterval. However, I am now trying to do the same but in my setInterval code I am trying to call a function that returns a promise. I only want to reset my interval once the function I am calling inside the setInterval, that returns a promise, has completed. I can't see how to do this. My code is as follows:

```
var repeatXTimes = config.repeatXTimes;
var sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds = config.sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds;
var runInfinitely = repeatXTimes == configConstants.REPEAT_INFINITE;

if (runInfinitely || repeatXTimes > 0) {

    var timesRun = 0;

    var interval = setInterval(function () {

        timesRun++;

        if (!runInfinitely && timesRun >= repeatXTimes) {       

            clearInterval(interval);
        }       

        user.runAllOfTheConfiguredCommands().then(function (respone) {

            // I only want to to set this interval to run again, once this function is complete....

        });
    }, sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds * 1000););
}
```

Please can anybody advise how this can be achieved. I have tried searching but cannot see a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function returns a Promise, I believe you can `await` it (the syntax is simpler than callbacks) :

```
const repeatXTimes = config.repeatXTimes,
      sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds = config.sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds,
      runInfinitely = repeatXTimes == configConstants.REPEAT_INFINITE;

const run = async () => {
    await user.runAllOfTheConfiguredCommands()
    timesRun++
    if (runInfinitely || timesRun < repeatXTimes) setTimeout( run, sleepBetweenRepeatingAllOfTheCommandsSeconds * 1000 )
}

run()
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thank you very much. This is a very neat solution. I couldn't figure it out but this does the job and is much more readable.

Comment: You're welcome. Yeah, async/await kicks ass :) I suggest you to read [this article](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) about it if you haven't already.